# Protocol Buffer Java implementation with annotations like ProtoBuf-net

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm looking for Java implementation of Protocol Buffer using annotation the same way it is implemented in [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted) project.
I just want the easy of use of annotation without the need to constantly compile the .proto file using protoc.

Comment: Hmmm... If only I knew java as well as I know .net :p

Comment: Do you mean looking at the code of protobuf-net and translate it to Java?

Comment: I mean I'm the author of protobuf-net, and it would be an interesting challenge to port it; unfortunately my java knowledge is fairly minimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Protostuff library can serialize annotated POJOs: https://protostuff.github.io/docs/protostuff-runtime/

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. I'll try to use it inside Jersey container

Answer (score -1):

Aside from great Protostuff library that is already mentioned, perhaps you might also consider trying out JSON instead -- unless you absolutely must use protobuf due to compatibility reasons.
JSON processing on Java is not only very convenient (annotation-based, auto-detection), it is also competitive in performance (see [jvm-serializers](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki) results, for example).